# Batch provision users in the database or via script using API calls

Tags: authentication, ldap, liferay, liferay-6, peoplesoft

I have a requirement to batch provision users in the Liferay sourced from  PeopleSoft custom table or set of tables via a feed. We are front-ending PeopleSoft with Liferay for a better user experience.

- These users are not in our LDAP system (so we can't use SSO and import users on login) but currently access some scaled down functions in PeopleSoft.
- We need to provision them in Liferay from PeopleSoft somehow and have them login to Liferay and do other portlet development/integration tasks to allow them to see their data from PeopleSoft.
- We also need to import these users roles/group/what they should have access to from PeopleSoft and sync it with Liferay.

I know there is no LDAP/Authentication integration to any external sourced database tables in Liferay out of the box other than the default LDAP, CAS etc...

So, I am wondering if anyone has tried to do batch Liferay user provisioning where users are created and provisioned in Liferay via a script with API calls or direct database updates from a feed etc.?

Is this feasible or recommended? I would appreciate any feedback on this.

I have not found anything so far on this but will digging deeper into it. I will update and report back on what I find.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Updating database directly is not recommended by Liferay, Its always good to use API for adding/updating user entity.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do SOAP messaging?

You could trigger the message on SavePostChange of the USERMAINT component.  Or do it in batch with a custom App Engine or similar other process.

Info:
https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/soap-web-services